# dropping index in a table with 8 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I am trying to execute the following:

```
DROP INDEX idx_deletedAt_isLocked_testi ON app_instagram_shop_picture;
DROP INDEX idx_id_deletedAt_isLocked ON app_instagram_shop;
```

currently I am using mysql 5.6 InnoDB and this is taking more than 2 hours to execute on a table which has 8 million rows. How do I speed this up? It seems when I try to run this all other processes are stuck on 'waiting table lock'

Comment: I am surprised at that. What other indexes and foriegn keys do these tables have?

Comment: Dropping an index should be like erasing it from a book...it takes very little time...I suspect that there is a metadata lock on the table I would kill the top connection with "waiting table lock'  (especially if its just a select) and then proceed down the line kiling the connection (where possible)...

Comment: In 5.6 dropping an index is mapped to an ALTER TABLE and that then involves copying the table. No wonder it is taking so long. Seem really silly to me.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-index.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Comment: ALTER TABLE in 5.6 should have some new feature that doesn't interrupt read/write in it

Comment: Yes, they are suspended until the alter table is finished. Reading further it says that drop index does not actually require a table copy for drop index. I thought the whole thing was just delete the inx file and update the schema information, which should take no time at all.

Comment: @David with decent hardware it should not take any time at all, I have dropped indexes on tables with 47million records with over 4k reads per a seconds in literally seconds on decent hardware with 12G Ram...Where do you see that the entire table is copied?

Comment: @Adit...You are Altering the table whether its doing a complete copy or not..This is not postgres...Mysql Innodb will block writes during that time... Reads are still a go but when you get a Metadata table lock out it deadlocks

Comment: @BK435 I would say my hardware is decent enough 12 GB ram and 8 cores.

Comment: @David Yes...that is correct...But the problem is that it takes 2 separate commands to do that on one connection....If there is another connection that is trying to write/read from the table as the drop index command tries to go from the Alter table to the update schema information...IT WILL DEADLOCK since the original alter table connection cannot get a lock on the table...its a bit buggy if you ask me

Comment: @Adit kill the pending connection that are showing table lock...Your schema will be able to update the fact that you have dropped the index and will finish in a second...You are deadlocked right now..U have been sitting and waiting on nothing for 2 hours to complete